# Смартфон чи мудрофон?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, синоніми, неологізми

Одного разу почув в оглядах на одному українському youtube-каналі вживання слова "мудрофон" для означення мобільного телефону. Потім зустрів в описах характеристик пристрою. І, наразі, дуже часто став помічати використання саме слова "мудрофон". Отож стало цікаво, яким словом "смартфон" чи "мудрофон" більш доцільніше називати сучасний мобільний телефон?

У Новітньому онлайному словнику української мови (2013-2018) зокрема [зазначено](http://sum.in.ua/f/smartfon):

> **смартфо́н**, -а, чол. Стільниковий телефон із можливістю виконання додаткових застосунків та доступом до Інтернету.
>   Смартфони — це мобільні телефони з повноцінною операційною системою (Symbian OS, Windows Mobile, Palm OS тощо), що відкрита для розроблення програмного забезпечення сторонніми розробниками *(Теорія та практика судової експертизи і криміналістики, 2009, № 9)*;

І Вікі каже, що

> [Смартфо́ни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD) (з англ. smart — розумний, і англ. phone — телефон) — окрема категорія телефонів, які — на відміну від простих стільникових телефонів — мають більше оперативної пам'яті і власний потужний, як для кишенькових пристроїв процесор, працюють під операційною системою Symbian 6.1 і вище, операційними системами платформи Windows Mobile 5 і вище або Palm OS, операційною системою iOS, Android, Tizen, Bada. Завдяки таким даним підтримують багато програм написаних на C++ та java зокрема 3D-ігри.

На Словотворі спільнота пропонує [переклад](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/smartfon) слова "смартфон" як "мудрофон".

І в Пінгвінів [теж](https://pingvin.pro/gadgets/article-gadget/rechi-yaki-mudrofon-vykreslyv-z-nashoho-zhyttya.html) "мудрофон"

Отож чи можна використовувати всі два слова як синоніми для позначення одного й того ж предмету? Чи таки треба користуватись якимсь конкретно?

Answer (score 6):

Ось визначення з [Google перекладача](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/smart):

> [image]

Зазвичай *smart* має на увазі швидке. Швидкий розум, швидку дію. Мудрий асоціюється із неспішністю, зауважте, серед запропонованих синонімів немає *wise*. Гадаю, що *мудрофон* - це невдалий словотвір і вживати його не варто.

Comment: От що, що, а переклади Гугла я б перевіряв, ось наприклад одне з трактувань значень в [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smart):
_informal_ Having or showing a quick-witted intelligence.
‘if he was that smart he would never have been tricked’

Comment: @m0rpheus як трактування з Oxford Dictionaries заперечує мою відповідь?

Comment: Перепрошую за неуважність читання/розуміння Вашого коментара і відповідно надання безграмотної відповіді. Давайте разом розберемось та проаналізуємо: маємо роз'яснення "Having or showing a quick-witted intelligence - (якщо я правильно розумію і перекладаю, не без допомоги того самого Гугла, то) - Маючий або демонструючий раціональний (винахідливий, дотепний) розум". А якщо звернутися до тлумачень слова [мудрий](http://sum.in.ua/s/mudryj), то, як на мене, то більш відповідного слова не знайти. До того ж в антонімах до smart і quick-witted слова wise ніби теж немає:

Comment: `smart` https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smart ; `quick-witted` https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick-witted

Comment: @m0rpheus при перекладі ви пропустили слово *quick*. А в тлумаченні слова мудрий в  1 і 2 говориться про досвід, а досвід - це дуже повільна/інертна штука. Тобто мудрий може дати хорошу пораду, але може бути не придатним для участі в конкурсі, тоді як кмітливий, це саме здатний швидко знайти відповідь.

Comment: та вроді нічого не пропускав... quick-witted intelligence - раціональний розум (https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=uk&tab=wT#en/uk/quick-witted%20intelligence). Бачу, що наша полеміка плавно перетікає з русла лінгвістики в етимологію? ;-) 
До речі, термін `wise` присутній в синонімах, які пропонує Гугл до `smart`: строчка `тямущий | clever, smart, bright, capable, **wise**, comprehensive`...

Comment: Ви ж самі навели посилання на webster з поясненням *quick-witted*, там чітко сказано про швидкість. Щодо синонімів, то я не певен, що тут діє правило транзитивності.

Comment: @m0rpheus і навіть *раціональний розум* ,це теж далеко від *мудрості*.

Comment: Тоді, мабуть, прийдеться писати Мартіну Куперу листа, щоб допоміг нам визначитись з назвою...

Comment: @m0rpheus але ж ви справді іґноруєте слово quick.

Comment: _Клепкофон_ :). Телефон, якому не бракує клепки. Це так, у ролі жарту.

Answer (score 2):

Одразу ж виникає логічне питання: "Чи є сенс заміняти/перекладати "смартфон" як "мудрофон", коли у нас все одно залишається частина "[-фон](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)", яка є запозиченням з англ. "phone")?"

На рахунок вживання слова "мудрофон". Його ви не побачете в жодному із відомих офіційних словників, тому я гадаю, що не варто використовувати це слово, наприклад, в офіцйно-ділових текстах чи навіть наукових (зазначу, що це моя думка і знову ж таки базується вона на тому, що цього слова немає в словниках).

Можливо колись цей неологізм буде більш вживаним і з'явиться в якомусь словнику, однак, знову ж таки чи є сенс заміняти "смартфон" на "мудрофон"? Я не впевнений.